# As soon as protractor execute first it block gives an error :-Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page

Tags: protractor

```
describe('Login Scenarios', function () {

    it('First IT block', function () {
        browser.get('http:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
        browser.manage().window().maximize();
        LoginPage.Login(USERNAME, PASSWORD);

    });   
    it('Second IT block', function () {
        browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);        
        Properties.logout.click();
        Properties.confirmlogout.click();
        AutomationUtility.hold();
    });
});
```

When I keep all the code in first IT block it runs fine but when divided into multiple test cases protractor will execute first IT block only, after that it gives an error message as:-

```
Error: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "both angularJS testability and angular testability are undefined.  This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details
```

Then, Protractor does not close the browser and gives the error messages of not finding element etc as protractor running test cases in chronological order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to resolve by putting URL in onPrepare section. In to configuration protractor.conf.js file:-

return browser.get('http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/login');

Thus the protractor is not failing when clicked on the login button. Also not getting any  Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page.

Answer (score 0):

Move `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);` to configuration `protractor.conf.js` file into `onPrepare` section.

```
export let config = {
  ...
  ...
  onPrepare () => {
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    ...
  },
  ...
  ... 
};
```

Or disable wait for angular before `browser.get()`, then enable after `browser.get()`

```
describe('Login Scenarios', function () {

    it('First IT block', function () {
        // disable if opening page is non-angular page
        browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);  
        browser.get('http:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');

        // revert back to enable, after the non-angular page opened.
        browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);  

        browser.manage().window().maximize();
        LoginPage.Login(USERNAME, PASSWORD);

    });   
    it('Second IT block', function () {               
        Properties.logout.click();
        Properties.confirmlogout.click();
        AutomationUtility.hold();
    });
});
```

Comment: Oleksii, thanks for the response it does resolve the problem but it takes way the prime capability of the protractor, as protractor does not aware when will be Angular is going to be Enabled and thus causes issues like "element not interactable". Which I am faceing right now.

Comment: tried the waitForAngularEnabled:- true/fasle it is not working                  
it('First IT block', function () {            
        browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);   
     .XXXXX
               browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);                                               });

Comment: You should add explicit waiter before action with element.

Comment: Tried explicit wait (browser.sleep(5000) before action with element but getting the same result.

Comment: so, the error is right. Sorry but it is another question.

Comment: you don't show your html, how you search your element. That's why "element not interactable" is totally different issue. Read please the summary of your question.